# many to many table in django without using manytomanyfield

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

rather than using the models.ManyToMany field in django

i just set up a intermediary field with a bunch of foreign keys.

is there any reason why this wouldn't work. I can't think of any but why not see if any of you have tried the same.

```
class Authorization(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             )
    permission = models.ForeignKey( 'venueadmin.Permissions', blank=True, null=True)

    #venue = models.ForeignKey(venue)   <-- commented out cause I haven't made the model its referencing yet.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is exactly how  ManyToMany relationships work, except few things to consider.

First, you might want to check how Django generates `ManyToManyField` [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3c447b108ac70757001171f7a4791f493880bf5b/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L1108). It does almost the same you did here.

Now, before starting using separate model think about next things:

- database constraint is missing. It means that there is no validation
  on what has been put in to the `Authorization` table as example -
  Duplicate rows;
- there is no indexation which means that search will become slow once Authorization grows. Interesting enough I did not find it in Django, maybe nobody cares? Two columns table might not be so critical;
- there is no reason to keep an authorization record for user with no `permissions`. What is the reason of setting `permissions` to NULL? Does it carry any useful information for DB administrator in future?